# Biggest furniture that can go through a door sized 1 into a room 3 $\times$ 3?

Tags: geometry

In a 2-dimension world , there's a room sized 3 $\times$ 3, at one of its walls, there's an open door with width 1, positioned in the middle of the wall.

What is the biggest ( in the sense of area) solid furniture , that could be moved into this room via the door?

Comment: Is it immediately obvious that you can do better than a $1 \times 3$ rectangle?

Comment: @mjqxxxx yes. So $x \ge 3$. But $x=?$

Comment: If you take a knight's path and round off the corner of the L into a quarter circle to make a J shape, it works. So $x \ge 3 + \pi / 4$. Problems like these are usually computationally tough though; e.g., [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem)

Comment: @PaulLeVan thanks for the link!